# How can I prevent Wordpress users from permanently deleting posts from trash?

Tags: wordpress

For security reasons, I need to prevent users from permanently deleting posts from trash, while keeping the ability to trash posts and restore them from trash.

This code prevents users from permanently deleting drafts, but it also prevents them from restoring from trash:

```
add_filter ('user_has_cap', 'prevent_deletion', 10, 3);
 
function prevent_deletion ($allcaps, $caps, $args) {
    if (isset($args[0]) && isset($args[2]) && $args[0] == 'delete_post') {
        $post = get_post ($args[2]);
        if ($post->post_status == 'trash') {
            $allcaps[$caps[0]] = false;
        }
    }
    return $allcaps;
}
```

The if statement here is too broad (it prevents all actions with trashed posts, not just deleting), but I don't know how to make it more specific. Or, if this is not the right path, what to do instead to achieve the goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

edit in your wp-config.php file.

```
define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 1 );
```

//Integer is the amount of days

Comment: Thanks, does not answer the question though

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
function modify_pre_delete_post_defaults($delete, $post, $force_delete) { 
    return true; 
}
add_filter( "pre_delete_post", "modify_pre_delete_post_defaults", 10, 3 );
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_delete_post/